# UIButton inherit selected state

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uikit

I have a `UIButton` inside a custom cell. Upon selecting the cell, the button changes it state to *"highlighted"* as well.

I'd like to prevent that behaviour. The button should change its state only when it's specifically touched (I take care of that in my `IBAction`).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I used eventually (inside my Custom cell implementation):

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    BOOL highlightState = self.btn.highlighted;
    BOOL selectedState = self.btn.selected;

    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    self.btn.selected = selectedState;
    self.btn.highlighted = highlightState;
}

- (void) setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    BOOL highlightState = self.btn.highlighted;
    BOOL selectedState = self.btn.selected;

    [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];

    self.btn.selected = selectedState;
    self.btn.highlighted = highlightState;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can subclass `UIButton` and override the `setSelected:` method and not call `[super setSelected:]` or call it with `[super setSelected:NO];`

If you want to select it yourself, call `[super setSelected:YES];`

Answer (score 0):

In your cell's class override:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
  self.button.highlighted = NO;
}
```